# AngularJS - how to write a unit test containing the momentjs library?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, karma-jasmine

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5.3.

I want to test one of my services and I want to use momentjs in the tests.

test example:

```
it('should have the correct number of weeks in the calendar month for Feb', function () {
    var dateString = '2018-02-01';
    Calendar.data.currentCalendarMonth = moment(dateString).startOf('month');
    Calendar.buildMonth();
    var start = moment(dateString).startOf('month').isoWeek();
    var end = moment(dateString).endOf('month').isoWeek();
    expect(end - start + 1).toBe(Object.keys(Calendar.data.weeks).length);
});
```

When I run the tests I get this error:

```
TypeError: moment(...).year(...).week is not a function
```

I have tried to import momentjs in my karma config file but it had no effect.

Edit: Moment is listed as a dependency in my bower config file. I tried to put the moment files before my files in karma config but it didn't help the result. 
moment(...).year(...).week is used in my Calendar service but not in my unit test there.

Comment: What does the files array of your karma config look like? Is moment.js referenced before you reference your local files?

Comment: Have you added moment as a dependency in package.json? Have you imported it in your spec file?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Week function is not used in your code.